# Count and print values of HTTP API

Tags: php, matomo

Looking for help in counting all values that are present in HTTP API. The link below outputs the values of multiple data points by date. What I am trying to achieve is a **count** on each value so that instead of

```
a:2:{s:10:"2018-01-03";a:9:{s:12:"nb_pageviews";d:2031;}s:10:"2018-01-04";a:9:{s:12:"nb_pageviews";d:25;}
```

I want to output the above nb_pageviews as a key with the value of the dates combined - 2056.

Example Link for API is https://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=Actions.get&idSite=7&period=day&date=last2&format=php&token_auth=anonymous

And the PHP to display this is

```
$url = "https://demo.piwik.org/";
$url .= "?module=API&method=Actions.get";
$url .= "&idSite=7&period=day&date=last2";
$url .= "&format=php";
$url .= "&token_auth=anonymous";

$fetched = file_get_contents($url);
$content = unserialize($fetched);

// case error
if (!$content) {
   print("NO DATA");
}

foreach ($content as $row) {
   $pageviews = $row['nb_pageviews'];

   print("<div>$pageviews</div>\n");       
}
```

Please note that the above link contains multiple other values that I will be wanting to do the same with, yet for ensuring the readability of this question I have kept the values simple and to just the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [combined assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), and be sure to set defaults of 0, before the loop.

```
$fetched = 'a:2:{s:10:"2018-01-03";a:9:{s:12:"nb_pageviews";d:2031;s:17:"nb_uniq_pageviews";d:964;s:12:"nb_downloads";d:2;s:17:"nb_uniq_downloads";d:2;s:11:"nb_outlinks";d:68;s:16:"nb_uniq_outlinks";d:64;s:11:"nb_searches";d:33;s:11:"nb_keywords";d:16;s:19:"avg_time_generation";d:0.78600000000000003;}s:10:"2018-01-04";a:9:{s:12:"nb_pageviews";d:25;s:17:"nb_uniq_pageviews";d:10;s:12:"nb_downloads";i:0;s:17:"nb_uniq_downloads";i:0;s:11:"nb_outlinks";d:1;s:16:"nb_uniq_outlinks";d:1;s:11:"nb_searches";d:2;s:11:"nb_keywords";d:2;s:19:"avg_time_generation";d:0.79300000000000004;}}';

$content = unserialize($fetched);

// case error
if (!$content) {
   print("NO DATA");
}

$pageviews         = 0;
$uniq_pageviews    = 0;
// and on, with your other vars you're looking to sum...

foreach ($content as $row) {
   $pageviews      += $row['nb_pageviews'];
   $uniq_pageviews += $row['nb_uniq_pageviews'];
}

var_export(['pageviews' => $pageviews, 'uniq_pageviews' => $uniq_pageviews]);
```

Working demo: https://eval.in/930183

```
// Output
array (
    'pageviews' => 2056.0,
    'uniq_pageviews' => 974.0,
)
```

To print these values, you might replace the `var_export` line with something like this:

```
$data = [
    'pageviews'      => $pageviews,
    'uniq_pageviews' => $uniq_pageviews
];
```

Which you could output in some HTML like so:

```
<div class="col-md-4"><?php echo $data['pageviews']; ?></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><?php echo $data['uniq_pageviews']; ?></div>
```

Comment: That is brilliant thank you. How can I `print` these values as `<div class="col-md-4">$pageviews</div>`? Also, without decimal?

Comment: Will make an edit to explain. Thanks for accepting! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great as it has just solved a few other issues that I could see arising. Being able to add this as a function and use this data across multiple pages now allows me to give control to the user for editing the dates of analytics. Awesome stuff.